# How can I grep contents of files with bash only without using find or grep -r?

Tags: bash

would like to write a bash program which if I type in the following:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./sample.sh path regex keyword
```

that will result something like that:

```
path/sample.txt:12

path/sample.txt:34

path/dir/sample1.txt:56

path/dir/sample2.txt:78
```

I have absolutely no idea how can I achieve this without using find or grep -r (but I can use grep/ sed/ awk) in bash... Please help...

Thank you very much!!

Comment: [Also asked on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227099/how-can-i-grep-contents-of-files-with-bash-only-without-using-find-or-grep-r). [Don't do this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting).

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s globstar
awk '/search-string/ { print FILENAME ":" NR }' **/*
```

`globstar` enables recursive globbing. `NR` holds the current line number.